# How to make used one to one relationship object disappear into django admin

Tags: python, django

I try to write a website for travel company, that we have number of hotels and each hotel have their unique room type as well as price. I create the model like this.

```
from django.db import models
class Room(models.Model):
    room_cat = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.OneToOneField('Price' ,unique=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Price(models.Model):
    period = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    rate  = models.DecimalField(max_digits=50000, decimal_places=10)

class Hotel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
    description = models.TextField(max_length = 200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length = 50)
    room = models.OneToOneField(Room,  primary_key=True, unique=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

However when I create these object in my django admin, some room types and price has pointed to particular hotel, however these used objects are still in my list when I create new hotel.
there are too many sub-categories and item. I need a user-friendly backend to input my data.
I read the django document for one to one relationship and admin but I am too frustrated not quite understand. what should I do for this issue?

Thanks so much

Comment: If I fully understood your question, you'll have to rethink about your models structure. I think your models don't match what you are looking for.

Comment: However you can custom your admin forms (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form) but I think there will be other problems after that! Because I think you are using OneToOneField in a wrong way!

Answer (score 0):

That won't work. You need your `Room` model to have a `ForeignKey` pointing to the `Hotel` model.

```
class Room(models.Model):
    hotel = models.ForeignKey(Hotel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Remove the `room` field from your `Hotel` model.

This will allow you to create multiple rooms for a single hotel. At present, your setup only allows you to link one room to one hotel.

I'm not 100% sure what you're doing with `Price`. I am assuming you want a price for each room and each period in the year. You could add a `ForeignKey` to your `Price` model, which will allow you to create multiple prices for each room.

```
class Price
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

You’re probably going to want some sort of end date on your `Price` model.

Then, you can add a room inline to your hotel admin page:

```
class RoomInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Room 

class HotelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [RoomInline]
```

That will allow you to view/edit the rooms for each hotel on that hotel's admin page.

You won’t be able to add a nested inline for the price, but you could link to the `RoomAdmin` from `RoomInline` by using `show_change_link = True`. Ultimately it might be better writing your own custom UI though.

Comment: the price is also unique like high/low season,  room type  , different period the price would be also different.  How to solve the problem?